# iOS UIActivityIndicator view not appearing in WKWebKit view

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

When I first run the app and the web page is loading the loading indicator shows as expected.

It then disappears as expected when the page loads.

I then navigate to a new web page and the indicator does not reappear

Any suggestions why please?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

        var webView: WKWebView!
        var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

        override func loadView() {

            let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
            let screenWidth = screenSize.width
            let screenHeight = screenSize.height

            webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width:screenWidth, height:screenHeight))
            webView.navigationDelegate = self
            //webView.uiDelegate = self
            view = webView
        }
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.bbc.co.uk")
            let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)

            webView.load(myRequest)

            activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
            activityIndicator.center = view.center
            //activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Page loading")
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Page loaded")
         activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the code below. The mistake you are doing is not updating to super class means `super.loadView()`.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController3: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView() 

        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height

        webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width:screenWidth, height:screenHeight))
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        //webView.uiDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)

        webView.load(myRequest)

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)
        activityIndicator.center = view.center
        //activityIndicator.style = .whiteLarge
        activityIndicator.color = .red
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        //activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Page loading")
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Page loaded")
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Comment: That leaves me with a blank screen.  Not sure why

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem with adding the subview.  But it hasn't solved the problem with the indicator only showing the first time the web page loads

Comment: I have tried on iPad on the simulator and it is displaying the loading indicator in the centre of the screen every time.  It is not doing so on the smaller iPhone 8 screen.  Maybe the screen dimensions are not set correctly?

Comment: It is working, the colour of the content in web view was obscuring the indicator

Comment: @Simon, I've already written the code for colouring the UIActivityIndicatorView thought you changed it to some other color. :)